# Can with() block results be used outside the block?

Tags: r

I've got a ton of means I want to compute for a data set with long variable names and levels. Since attach is frowned upon, I'm wondering if I can use a `with()` block, but have the results available after the block is closed.

Here's an example of statements I'm asking, but executed with `$` connectors. Mercury levels from various lake types in Maine:

```r
Y_O=mean(Maine$Mercury[Maine$Lake_Type=="Oligotropic"])
Y_M=mean(Maine$Mercury[Maine$Lake_Type=="Mesotropic"])
Y_E=mean(Maine$Mercury[Maine$Lake_Type=="Eutropic"])
```

I find it hard for readers to see what I'm on about.

I'd like to do this:

```r
with(Maine, {
  YGrand <- mean(Mercury)
  Y_O <- mean(Mercury[Lake_Type == "Oligotropic"])
  Y_M <- mean(Mercury[Lake_Type == "Mesotropic"])
  Y_E <- mean(Mercury[Lake_Type == "Eutropic"])
})
```

I'm already way over my page limit for this chapter, so I don't have space to introduce pipes. In the back of my mind, I seem to remember someone using another operator aside from `<-` in the assignments that elevated the results to regular user level. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Have you tried running this code? What happens? You may try `<<-` rather than `<-`. I know this is used when you're within `*apply()` functions.

Comment: Have you considered storing in a list and then accessing objects from the list? A list provides the flexibility to store different classes of objects within it.

Comment: Do you really want those as separate variables? Doesn't scale very well... even with just a couple more Lake Types this would get old fast. I'd use `tapply` or `aggregate`. `Y = with(Maine, tapply(Mercury, Lake_Type, mean))` works nicely and gives a named vector, you can then do, e.g.,    `Y["Oligotropic"]`.

Comment: Thanks to all. Perfect answers!

Comment: @CephBirk : That `<<-` is what I was thinking of. Full points for you.

Comment: @Gregor: Could you explain why the `tapply()` values are available outside the `with()` block? I thought things done withing `with()` were not available once the `with()` terminated (and hence my question). I very much like your answer, but can't explain why it works.

Comment: `with` "returns the value of the evaluated `expr`"---which means the last line of the expression if it is multiline. If you assign the with statement in your question, `x <- with(Maine, {...})` and then look at `x`, you'll have the value of the last line of your expression, the mean Mercury value for Eutropic lakes. But only a single value. `tapply` works because it is a vector of values, not a single value. This is also how d.b's answer works---it returns the data frame they create in the last line. It's also what NM_'s comment above is suggesting, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `aggregate` to apply a function over groups defined by elements in a list:

```
> aggregate(mtcars$hp, list(cyl = mtcars$cyl) ,mean)
  cyl         x
1   4  82.63636
2   6 122.28571
3   8 209.21429
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below could work but I'd find an alternative approach

```
x = with(mtcars, {
    c_all = mean(mpg)
    c_6 = mean(mpg[cyl == 6])
    c_4 = mean(mpg[cyl == 4])
    c_8 = mean(mpg[cyl == 8])
    data.frame(c_all, c_4, c_6, c_8)
})
list2env(x, envir = .GlobalEnv)

c_4
#[1] 26.66364
c_6
#[1] 19.74286
c_8
#[1] 15.1
c_all
#[1] 20.09062
```